# Request.pipe() unhandled Error exception Nodejs

Tags: node.js, request, fs

I'm trying to crawle my company's web site and I want to download all the existing images into a file. I'm using request.pipe() to do this but it gives unhandled error exception here is my code. What can be the problem?

```
$('a').each(function (index, a) {
            var toQueueUrl = $(a).attr('href');
            if(toQueueUrl.indexOf('.jpg') != -1){
                jpgUrlArr.push(toQueueUrl.toString());
            }
            c.queue(toQueueUrl);
        });
        for(var i=0 ; i<jpgUrlArr.length; i++){
            request(jpgUrlArr[i]).pipe(fs.createReadStream(imageStorageFolder + i + '.jpg'));
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two cases here:

1. Unhandled exceptions while you try to download image. You need to implement readStream on error event

code:

```
var readStream = request(jpgUrlArr[i])
readStream.on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err)
})

readStream.pipe(fs.createReadStream(imageStorageFolder + i + '.jpg'))
```

2. You can't download big amount of pics simultaneously. Sometimes you get socket errors. So try to limit async images loading. For examples - [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) nodejs module

code:

```
var async = require('async')
var elements = $('a')

async.eachLimit(elements, 4, function(element){
    // Downloading logic here
})
```

Comment: I'll try your answer and update the question. Thanks.